# ValueError: could not convert string to float when adding percentages

Tags: python, string

I'd like to change value in a dictionary which use string as value. Here is what I did:

```
extra_offset_left=0.4
style_image={'height':'300px','width': '100%','padding-left':'12%', 'padding-right':'10%'}

style_image['padding-left']=str(float(style_image['padding-left'])+extra_offset_left)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12%'
```

What I expect is 'padding-left' becomes 12%+0.4=52%

```
'padding-left':'52%'
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: I want output to be style_image={'height':'300px','width': '100%','padding-left':'52%', 'padding-right':'10%'}

Comment: `%` is not a numeral in the base-10 number system -- what did you expect?

Comment: Why bother switching between data types? What's the point of storing these data as strings if you plan to manipulate them arithmetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the digits to an integer and perform the addition:

```py
style_image['padding-left'] = f"{int(style_image['padding-left'][:-1]) + int(100 * extra_offset_left)}%"
```

This outputs:

```py
{'height': '300px', 'width': '100%', 'padding-left': '52%', 'padding-right': '10%'}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but if the original value was `padding-left:5%`, or `100%`, or there was a space at the beginning, this code wouldn't work. You should probably use a more robust method of matching the digits

Comment: yes i changed it to f"{int(style_image['padding-left'][:-1])+int(100*extra_offset_left)}%", so I use -1 to just include everything before %

Comment: @roudan even `[:-1]` isn't entirely robust, what if the string is `12% ` (with a space on the end)? Or it is in the form `20px`? OK, maybe I'm being a little pedantic but `re.findall(r'\d+', style_image['padding-left'])[0]` would seem safest.

Comment: Saftest would be not treating a string as a numeric type... but that's OP's problem not ours.

Comment: I think this can get out of hand _really_ quickly -- what if I have a field of `12% + 30px + 1em`? Yes, this code is a bit of a hack, but as @ddejohn points out this seems like there might be some other underlying issue that we don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer doesn't exactly answer OP's question, but since we're talking about a value that will be passed down to CSS, CSS has the [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) helper function that allows to do operations over css values. That means that you can, instead of computing this by yourself, leave it to css!
Here's an example:

```
extra_offset_left=0.4
style_image={'height':'300px','width': '100%','padding-left':'12%', 'padding-right':'10%'}

style_image['padding-left']=f"calc({style_image['padding-left']} + {int(100 * extra_offset_left)}%)"
```

and get the following:

```
{'height':'300px','width': '100%','padding-left':'calc(12% + 40%)', 'padding-right':'10%'}
```

And the computed css value of that expression will be  `padding-left: 52%`